# Racket: change dotted pair to list

Tags: list, racket, hashtable

I have a function that is calling hash-ref on two elements pulled from a hashtable. The first is the cdr of the hashkey and the second is a random listing from that hashkeys data.
But the data is being returned as a dotted list which causes hashref to fail because none of the keys are dotted pairs.
Is there an easy way to get the dotted pair to change to a list?

this is my function call

```
 (let ((data ( list-ref(hash-ref Ngram-table key) (random (length (hash-ref Ngram-table key))))))
```

I get an error saying that '("was" . "beginning") is not in the hashtable, is there a way to change key from '("was" . "beginning") to '("was" "beginning")?

```
(define (startup key value)
(cond 
[(> value 0) 
 ;(cons (car key) (cons (cdr key) null))

 (let ((data ( list-ref(hash-ref Ngram-table key) 
random (length (hash-ref Ngram-table key))))))

(display data) 
(startup (list*(cons (cdr key) (cons data null)))    (- value 1)))]) 
;(append (cdr key) data)
[(= value 0)
(display "END")])

 ; this function calls the startup function
(define (run-prog)
(test)
(display "ALICE was ") 
(startup '("ALICE" "was") 100))
```

Comment: You code doesn't compile and is incomplete. How should we be able to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something silly like:

```
(defun (listify-dotted-pair x) (list (car x) (cdr x)))
```

?

Comment: I tried that but it just changed my output to    key: '(("was") "beginning")    which didnt work either the extra parentheses mess up the hash-ref call

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of  issues with your supplied code. Parenthesis that are misplaced so that local variable `data` is access outside of `let` and enough closing to end both `cond` and `define` before the second `cond` term. It does not seem you are using DrRacket as an IDE as it clearly ident and show matching brackets for you.

I cannot see what `Ngram-table` but according to your question it seems to be a list rather than a hash table. Where is it made with `make-hash`? (I assume you need `equal?` to match e string keys). If you have a assoc with key values like `'((key . value) (key2 . value2))` you make your hash with : `(define Ngram-table (make-hash '(("key" . "value")("key2" . "value2"))))`

A second note:

`list*` is like `list` but the last argument is a list to be appended. Thus:

```
(list* 5 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (5 1 2 3)
```

You code, used in the recusion must be wrong:

```
(list* (cons (cdr key) (cons data null)))
```

Imagine you key being the list `("ALICE" "was")` and data being "happy" (I'm unsure if it's a list or not).. Then:

```
(cons (cdr key) (cons data '())) ; ==> (("was") "happy")
```

And `list*` of that will become the same list since it's only one argument.
If you need a element on the tail of a list you should do:

```
(append (cdr key) (cons data '())
```

Or if data from the hash is a list you simply do:

```
(append (cdr key) data)
```

If you need more help I really need to see an update to your question with some progress when it comes to the unbalanced `cond`/`let`.